# Implementing Wrapper of PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, spatial-database, postgis-2.0

How can I implement the Wrapper of PostgreSQL?

I found this [useful looking wrapper from a FOSS4G routing with pgRouting Workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html) but I do not know how to implement it!

Comment: I'd think you might want to ping the folks over at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I look at this question as a workflow question.  I've been working on a problem.  It is easy to just use the qgis database manager and plug a query in to generate some spatial data.  The problem is that I was working with an unsaved test project and all my stored queries in the project disappeared when I managed to lock up qgis.  So what if I store the query in the Postgresql database so that I can reuse it?  That would mean the query is not just stored in my qgis project file but the query is stored in the database where other people on my team can use the data by leveraging my work. The stored query is now available from qgis project to qgis project. Storing the query in the database because another way wrapping the query or procedure, a wrapper.  The end result is that all I store in the qgis project is

```
select rid, check_box, geom from my_test_raster( 5 )
```

The source query is from [this stack exchange question and answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110024/why-dont-all-the-attributes-in-the-sql-query-appear-in-table/110027) and looks like this

```
select row_number() over () as rid,
       'Visited ( ), count1 ( ), count2 ( ).'::text as xx,
       ST_AsText((gv).geom ) as geom
  from (
         Select ( ST_PixelAsPolygons( rast, 1 ) ) as gv
           from my_new_raster
          where rid = 5
       ) geoms
```

The one line wrapper is much easier to put in a qgis project than typing the same query over and over again.  If I want to use a different raster row, then I change 5 to another value.

The idea behind [Return route with network geometry](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html#return-route-with-network-geometry) section of your link is to become familiar with what you want to do by developing some experience with the data that you are querying.  In my query above I wanted to return the geometry of each pixel of a raster.  Since my original primary key of 5 will not be unique any longer, I used the row_number() function to generate a new unique value for qgis.

The idea behind [Visualize the result](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html#visualize-the-result) is to either generate a new table with the results of the query or use our approach of creating a wrapper function of our query via psql or PgAdminIII.  In both cases a query is created in qgis with the database manager.

The idea behind both the [Simplified input parameters and geometry output](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html#simplified-input-parameters-and-geometry-output) and [Route between lat/lon points and return ordered geometry with heading](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html#route-between-lat-lon-points-and-return-ordered-geometry-with-heading) sections is to create the wrapper once we know what we're trying to do by just querying our spatial database.  The second section is more involved because it has three queries involved in the wrapper function.  My wrapper function uses code from your link with a few changes.  The ideas are

- The first step drops the function so that I can build and test the procedure until it finally works.
- The function definition has a place for my one input parameter, 5, and what columns that I want out of the query.
- The function definition must return a record.
- I create some working variables: `sql` and `rec`.
- I define the query in a string with `sql := '';`
- Any single quotes, `'`, in the query string must be doubled to let Postgres know that I want a single quote at that point.  Some parts of the may end with a single quote. That means that I have to have three quotes in a row `'''`.
- I use a concatenation operator, `||`, to break up my query.
- Any input parameters must be referenced like my ridin parameter with `|| ridin ||`. This converts the input parameter into a string as part of the query string.  You may have some cases where you have to cast the variable with `::text`.
- I execute the query.  In each iteration of the loop you assemble a row to return from your function as a record.  Additional processing can occur before the rec.* columns are assigned to my output variables defined by the OUT parameters at the very beginning of the function definition.

There are many variations and improvements that can be made.  However, the format in this answer follows what was presented in [the pgrouting workshop wrapper examples](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html).  You will also need to follow any step up and configuration such as installing the pgrouting extension and create data to feed pgrouting.

The ideas and techniques are so good that I don't want to give this question to the DBAs as suggested.  I want to pickup these skills so that I can elevate my spatial game and simplify some of my work flow.

```
select rid, check_box, geom from my_test_raster( 5 )
```

That simple looking statement in my qgis project simplifies, clarifies, and communicates with others looking at my project.

---

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS my_test_raster(integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_test_raster (
    IN  ridin     integer,
    OUT rid       integer,
    OUT check_box varchar,
    OUT geom      geometry
)
    RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

    -- SQL variable to work up driving sql statement.
    sql     text;
    -- Record variable to process result set.
    rec     record;

BEGIN

    sql := 'select row_number() over () as rid, ' ||
            '''Visited ( ), count1 ( ), count2 ( )''::text as xx, ' ||
            'ST_AsText((gv).geom ) as geom ' ||
            'from ( ' ||
            'Select ( ST_PixelAsPolygons( rast, 1 ) ) as gv ' ||
            'from my_new_raster ' ||
            'where rid = ' || ridin ||
            ') geoms';

    FOR rec IN EXECUTE sql
        LOOP

            -- Return record
            rid          := rec.rid;
            check_box    := rec.xx;
            geom         := rec.geom;
            RETURN NEXT;

        END LOOP;

    RETURN;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE STRICT
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is an answer to the question?

Comment: I will revise the answer with an intro and conclusion. The idea is to simplify the problem by focusing on just the wrapper mechanics. The answer idea is based on the opening paragraphs of the [pgrouting tutorial](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html#), "Therefor pgRouting has decided to only support low-level functions and let the user write their own wrapper functions for their own use cases."