# Why don't all the attributes in the SQL query appear in table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have an SQL query that works fine in the DB Manager but when I load the table as a layer one column does not get loaded.  The different thing about this column is that it is static -- text generated with the query and the same for each row.

It is actually a template for data entry that I want to print on the reverse side of the map.  Effectively a check list for each item.  The only way I could see to get it printed was to add it as an attribute to each row.

eg.

```
<site name>  Vistited ( ), count1 (  ), count2 (  )....
```

so volunteers can check fill in the details and the photo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same problem.  After fooling around with the issue, I found out that all you need to do is add `::text` to the static value and make sure that you name the column with `as my_check_boxes`.  You will have to change the cast if text is not the actual data type.

```
select row_number() over () as rid,
       'Visited ( ), count1 ( ), count2 ( ).'::text as xx,
       ST_AsText( (gv).geom ) as geom
  from (
         select ( ST_PixelAsPolygons( rast, 1 ) ) as gv
           from my_new_raster
          where rid = 5
       ) geoms
```